# PostgreSQL and PQC

Tags: mysql, postgresql, memcached

I'm using MySQL with Memcached, but I'm planning to start using PostgreSQL instead of MySQL.

I know Memcached can work with PostgreSQL, but I found this online: [PostgreSQL Query Cache](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1296/). I've seen a presentation online, and it says memcached is used in this. But I don't understand: memcached, I have to "program" in my PHP-code, and PQC, not?

What's it all about? Is PQC the same as memcached, and could it replace memcached? For example: I have a table with all countries. It never changes, so I want to cache this instead of retrieving it from the database every time. Will PQC do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PQC is an implementation of caching that uses Memcached. It sits in front of your database server and caches query results for you. If you are running a lot of identical queries, this will make your database load a whole lot less and your return times a whole lot faster. It is not a substitute for good design of your application, but it can certainly help, and the cost of implementing it is extremely low since it takes advantage of an existing layer of abstraction.

Memcached is a lower level tool. A well designed application will leave you a nice place to put code between the business logic and the database layer to cache results, and this is where you put your memcached calls. In other words, if your code is designed to allow this abstraction, fantastic. Otherwise, you're looking at a lot more work to implement.